# Splitting a column in R with ifelse condition

Tags: r

I have a column called `Rooms` which has the following data:

```
'4+1' '3+1' '3' '2' '3+2' '4' '1' '2+1' '2+2' '5+1' '1+1' '6+1' '7+1' '5' '6' '0' '4+2' '8'
```

I wanted to split it to two columns where the delimiter is `+` and I did this by doing thee following:

```
splitingRoomsDF <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(out$Rooms),'+',fixed=TRUE)),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then in order to combine this dataframe with the main data I did:

```
data_final = cbind(out,splitingRoomsDF)
```

and when I printed it out I got this:
[image]

The problem with the above output is that if we have a cell value in `Rooms` that doesn't have the `+` delimiter it replace both `X1` and `X2` with that value and I want the value of `X2` to be zero if `Rooms` is without `+` delimiter. I'm not sure using if-else is the right thing to do here but going with that for now.

**So what should I change in my code lines above in order to accurately make this change.**

I've using this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/dragonduck/property-listings-in-kuala-lumpur

Comment: Try not deleting your question and posting it again edit it. It might annoy people who are trying to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tidyr::separate` which. handles this cleanly :

```
splitingRoomsDF <- tidyr::separate(out, Rooms, into = c('Room1', 'Room2'), 
                sep = "\\+",remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE, fill = "right")

head(splitingRoomsDF[, 1:5])

#                           Location        Price Rooms Room1 Room2
#1                KLCC, Kuala Lumpur RM 1,250,000   2+1     2     1
#2   Damansara Heights, Kuala Lumpur RM 6,800,000     6     6    NA
#3             Dutamas, Kuala Lumpur RM 1,030,000     3     3    NA
#4              Cheras, Kuala Lumpur                       NA    NA
#5         Bukit Jalil, Kuala Lumpur   RM 900,000   4+1     4     1
#6 Taman Tun Dr Ismail, Kuala Lumpur RM 5,350,000   4+2     4     2
```

If you want to set `NA`'s to 0, you could do

```
splitingRoomsDF[4:5][is.na(splitingRoomsDF[4:5])] <- 0
```